# dynamic PIVOT query with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table `Account`

```
Accountid            Calcul 

1                    27+23+12
4                    5+9+12
7                    7+12+20
```

I am looking to get the following table `AccountTemp`

```
Accountid                AccountCode

    1                    27
    1                    23
    1                    12
    4                    5
    4                    9
    4                    12 
    7                    7
    7                    12
    7                    20
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Bad way to store data.

Comment: @Mihai maybe that is why user3456466 is trying to change it

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/373f73/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

Create a split function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

Then do a query like this:

```
SELECT
    tbl.Accountid,
    split.AccountCode
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CAST(calc.Data AS INT) AS AccountCode
        FROM
            dbo.split(tbl.Calcul,'+') as calc
    ) as split
```

Output:

```
Accountid    AccountCode
1            27
1            23
1            12
4            5
4            9
4            12
7            7
7            12
7            20
```

Reference:

- [Split a string to a table using T-SQL](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/)
- [CROSS APPLY Explained](http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @account table(Accountid int, Calcul varchar(20))

--AccountTemp

insert @account values(1, '27+23+12')
insert @account values(4,'5+9+12')
insert @account values(7,'7+12+20')


create table #accounttemp(Accountid int, AccountCode int)

insert #accounttemp(Accountid, AccountCode)

SELECT Accountid, t.c.value('.', 'INT') AccountCode
FROM (
    SELECT Accountid, CAST('<t>' + 
        REPLACE(Calcul, '+', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML) x
        FROM @account
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)

select * from #accounttemp
drop table #accounttemp
```

Result:

```
Accountid   AccountCode
1           27
1           23
1           12
4           5
4           9
4           12
7           7
7           12
7           20
```